# How to register an Amazon Alexa Servlet in a Java Springboot 3.xx application

Tags: spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit, jakarta-migration

I managed to register the Amazon Servlet in a Spring Boot 2.xx Application like

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<SkillServlet> registerServlet(Skill skillInstance) {
    SkillServlet skillServlet = new SkillServlet(skillInstance);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(skillServlet, endpoint);
}
```

However, when I migrate to Spring Boot 3.xx I have a problem with Amazon SkillServlet deriving from `javax.servlet.Servlet` and Springboot 3.xx. `ServletRegistrationBean` is expecting the servlet to be a `jakarta.servlet.Servlet`. This problem already existed with the former Amazon Alexa implementation (Maven alexa-skills-kit), which forced me to stick to Spring Boot 2.xx, which also uses `javax.servlet.Servlet` and now it seems to be that the new Alexa ask SDK (Maven ask-sdk) still has the same problem.

What is the solution or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What did you do to make a servlet working with Spring-boot 3?